# Completely removing Node.js: automatic vs manual

Tags: node.js, bash, apt-get

Recently I used the following list of files associated with **node** to completely removing it on Linux Mint 18.1:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node* /usr/local/include/node* ~/.local/node* ~/.lib/node* ~/.include/node* /usr/local/bin/node*
```

On the other hand there is a solution for this which uses **apt-get**:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
```

Is there a difference in them in context of **full** and **total** removing nodejs from local machine? Which one is more correct/safe/complete?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much safer and more reliable to use `apt-get purge` for that. Otherwise you will have to know where all of your package files are located. This includes but not limited to: configuration files, man pages, libraries, etc. In addition, the package structure may change during time (like new files added or directories changed). The `apt-get` utility will also execute a set of post-removal scripts in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. If you keep removing files manually, your system will quickly be cluttered and may end up in an inconsistent state.

Here is a visual example (for Ubuntu):

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# rm -rf /usr/lib/node* /usr/include/node* /usr/bin/node*
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# updatedb
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# locate nodejs | head -n 3
/etc/profile.d/nodejs.sh
/usr/share/nodejs
/usr/share/doc/nodejs
# There are still more than 200 files left which are related to the nodejs package.
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# locate nodejs | wc -l
212
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really matter -- I mean "the package structure may change during time" and about various pieces in different locations...